# Cannot populate elasticsearch index using ```python manage.py search_index --rebuild``` in django using docker

Tags: python, django, docker, elasticsearch

I am using django, elasticsearch and postgresql from docker in separate containers. When I try to run `python manage.py search_index --rebuild`, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\manage.py", line 18, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\venv\lib\site-packages\django_elasticsearch_dsl\management\commands\search_index.py", line 166, in handle
        self._rebuild(models, options)
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\venv\lib\site-packages\django_elasticsearch_dsl\management\commands\search_index.py", line 143, in _rebuild
        if not self._delete(models, options):
      File "C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar\venv\lib\site-packages\django_elasticsearch_dsl\management\commands\search_index.py", line 132, in _delete
        "the '{}' indexes? [y/N]: ".format(", ".join(index_names)))
    TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Everything else works fine. When I run `docker-compose up`, all of my containers i.e. the postgresql database, web service and the elasticsearch containers start running without any problems. The website starts running on `localhost:8000` and I can also create new users from the admin panel. So, the website and database are working fine. On `localhost:9200`, I can see the following JSON:

```
    {
      "name" : "4336b15c63fa",
      "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
      "cluster_uuid" : "a_long_string",
      "version" : {
        "number" : "7.14.2",
        "build_flavor" : "default",
        "build_type" : "docker",
        "build_hash" : "a_long_string",
        "build_date" : "2021-09-15T10:18:09.722761972Z",
        "build_snapshot" : false,
        "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
        "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
        "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
      },
      "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
    }
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    version: '3.8'
    
    services:
      db:
        container_name: db_ramrobazar
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        # environment:
        #   - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        #   - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        #   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        ports:
          - '5432:5432'
        volumes:
          - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        env_file: .env
        networks:
          - djangonetwork
      
    
      web:
        container_name: web_ramrobazar
        build:
          context: .
        depends_on:
          - db
        command: >
          sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations && 
                 python manage.py migrate &&
                 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        env_file: .env
        links:
          - db:db
        networks:
          - djangonetwork
        volumes: 
          - .:/usr/src/app
      
      
      esearch:
        container_name: search
        image: elasticsearch:7.14.2
        environment:
          - discovery.type=single-node
        ports:
          - '9200:9200'
    
    
    
    volumes:
      postgres_data:
    
    
    networks:
      djangonetwork:
        driver: bridge
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
    FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
    
    
    # setting work directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    
    # env variables
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    ENV PYTHONDONTWEITEBYTECODE 1
    
    # install psycopg dependencies
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        libpq-dev \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
    
    # install dependencies
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip
    COPY requirements.txt .
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    
    
    COPY . .
```

My `documents.py`:

```
    from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document
    from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
    from .models import User
    
    
    @registry.register_document
    class UserDocument(Document):
    
        class index:
            name = 'user'
        
        class Django:
            model = User
            fields = ['id', 'first_name',]
```

My `settings.py`:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'phonenumber_field',
        'ramrobazar.account.apps.AccountConfig',
        'ramrobazar.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
        'ramrobazar.inventory.apps.InventoryConfig',
        'mptt',
        'django_elasticsearch_dsl',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
    .
    .
    .
    ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
        'default' : {'hosts': '127.0.0.1:9200'}
    }
```

This is my first time using both docker and elasticsearch. Please let me know if anything else is needed.

**Edit**:

I have changed the `class index` to `class Index` in my `documents.py` file.
But now I get the following error when running `docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py search_index --rebuild`:

```
    (venv) C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar>docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py search_index --rebuild
    [+] Running 1/0
     - Container db_ramrobazar  Running                                                                                0.0s
    Are you sure you want to delete the 'user' indexes? [y/N]: y
    Deleting index 'user'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
        conn = connection.create_connection(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
        raise err
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
        sock.connect(sa)
    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 255, in perform_request
        response = self.pool.urlopen(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
        retries = retries.increment(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 525, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 770, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
        httplib_response = self._make_request(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
        super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
        raise NewConnectionError(
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd41c749c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
      File "manage.py", line 18, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 166, in handle
        self._rebuild(models, options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 143, in _rebuild
        if not self._delete(models, options):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 139, in _delete
        index.delete(ignore=404)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/index.py", line 405, in delete
        return self._get_connection(using).indices.delete(index=self._name, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 347, in _wrapped
        return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 334, in delete
        return self.transport.perform_request(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 417, in perform_request
        self._do_verify_elasticsearch(headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 606, in _do_verify_elasticsearch
        raise error
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 569, in _do_verify_elasticsearch
        _, info_headers, info_response = conn.perform_request(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 280, in perform_request
        raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
    elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd41c749c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd41c749c10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

**Edit 2**:

I found a similar problem as mentioned in the first edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684381/elasticsearch-with-django-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection-errno-111-con) and I tried the solution provided there. It said that I had to change the hosts in my `settings.py` from `localhost:9200` to the name of the service in `docker-compose.yml`. So, I changed it to `esearch`.

Updated `settings.py`:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
            'phonenumber_field',
            'ramrobazar.account.apps.AccountConfig',
            'ramrobazar.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
            'ramrobazar.inventory.apps.InventoryConfig',
            'mptt',
            'django_elasticsearch_dsl',
            'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        ]
        .
        .
        .
        ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
            'default' : {'hosts': 'esearch'}
        }
```

But then I get the following error when running `docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py search_index --rebuild`:

```
    (venv) C:\Users\ashut\Desktop\ramrobazar>docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py search_index --rebuild
    [+] Running 1/0
     - Container db_ramrobazar  Running                                                                                0.0s
    Are you sure you want to delete the 'user' indexes? [y/N]: y
    Deleting index 'user'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
        conn = connection.create_connection(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
        for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
        for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 255, in perform_request
        response = self.pool.urlopen(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
        retries = retries.increment(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 525, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 770, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
        httplib_response = self._make_request(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
        super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
        self.connect()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
        raise NewConnectionError(
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe5e33aac40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        main()
      File "manage.py", line 18, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 166, in handle
        self._rebuild(models, options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 143, in _rebuild
        if not self._delete(models, options):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 139, in _delete
        index.delete(ignore=404)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/index.py", line 405, in delete
        return self._get_connection(using).indices.delete(index=self._name, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 347, in _wrapped
        return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 334, in delete
        return self.transport.perform_request(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 417, in perform_request
        self._do_verify_elasticsearch(headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 606, in _do_verify_elasticsearch
        raise error
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 569, in _do_verify_elasticsearch
        _, info_headers, info_response = conn.perform_request(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 280, in perform_request
        raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
    elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe5e33aac40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe5e33aac40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

Comment: Should you be running the command in your container - `docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py search_index --rebuild`? Looks like you are running on the host machine

Comment: I have tried that. I get the same error.

Comment: The nested index class should be capitalised in your Document -  `class Index:`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But now I get another error. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am not sure how it works but I think I found a solution. I was just trying out random different things. Since the error I was getting was a ConnectionError, I tried removing all the 'network' related lines from my `docker-compose.yml` and it somehow worked.

My new `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    version: '3.8'
    
    services:
      db:
        container_name: db_ramrobazar
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        ports:
          - '5432:5432'
        volumes:
          - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        # env_file: .env
        # networks:
        #   - djangonetwork
      
    
      web:
        container_name: web_ramrobazar
        build:
          context: .
        depends_on:
          - db
        command: >
          sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
                 python manage.py migrate &&
                 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        env_file: .env
        # links:
        #   - db:db
        # networks:
        #   - djangonetwork
        volumes: 
          - .:/usr/src/app
      
      
      esearch:
        container_name: search
        image: elasticsearch:7.14.2
        environment:
          - discovery.type=single-node
        ports:
          - '9200:9200'
    
    
    
    volumes:
      postgres_data:
    
    
    # networks:
    #   djangonetwork:
    #     driver: bridge
```

Now, the command `docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py search_index --rebuild` works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

if your wish is to populate , then don't use rebuild flag , instead use --populate flag.

The error is found in documents.py file . that is , you need to configure shards and replicas for your document.

The connection error occurs mainly due to elastic search connection. you need to run elasticsearch in background.

sometimes connection timeout may happen , if so increase the timeout in settings under ELASTICSEARCH section.

thanks